# Understanding error in the insertion of an element in a list

Tags: haskell

So I'm learning haskell right now, and I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong for the following function that inserts an element `x` at index `k` in list `l`

1.`insertElem x k l = take k l ++ (x : drop k l)`

2.`insertElem x k l = (take k l : x) ++ drop k l`

Now, I know that the correct answer is number 1, but I don't understand why number 2 is wrong for the call `insertElem 2 5 [0,0,0,0,0,0]`.

The error is "Cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]. Expected type: [[a]], Actual type: [a]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is (as Silvio already told you) the use of `:` but let's analyse the types to see where the error comes from and how you could see it yourself:

#### let's check the types

look at

```
(take k l : x) ++ drop k l
```

`(++)` has type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` so both parts `take k l : x` and `drop k l` need to be lists of the same type.

looking at `drop` you get `Int -> [a] -> [a]` so you now know:

- `k` has type `Int`
- `l` has type `[a]`
- your result is the same type `[a]`
- `take k l : x` too needs to have type `[a]`

now look at `(:)` it has type `a -> [a] -> [a]` so for it to work out you now need `x` to have type `[a]` and `take k l` to have type `a`.

`take` has type `Int -> [a] -> [a]` and we already know that `l` has type `[a]` so you get:

- `take k l` has type `[a]`
- but you also need (see above at `(:)`) `take k l` to be of type `a`

So you need `a` to be somehow at the same time to be `[a]` that is what `a ~ [a]` means and is what the error says.

Answer (score 4):

The `:` operation adds an element (the first argument) to a list (the second argument). Thus, it expects the first argument to be an element and the second to be a list, not the other way around. If you want to do it that way, you would do this:

```
insertElem x k l = take k l ++ [x] ++ drop k l
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive definition of `insertElem` that illustrates the use of `(:)`,

```
insertElem :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertElem e 0 xs     = e : xs
insertElem e k []     = [e] -- k > length xs
insertElem e k (x:xs) = x : insertElem e (k-1) xs
```

Here `insertElem` delivers a list of `a` to which we append either the current head of the list of else the actual element to be inserted.

The appending of an element of type `a` to a list of `a` uses `(:)`. Note in the second case we append an element `e` to an empty list, namely `[e]`; this is equivalent to `e : []`. In the last case we extract the head of the list also with `(:)`.